# Какую СУБД выбрать?

Tags: java, android, база-данных, firebase

Доброго времени всем. Нужна помощь по выбору базы данных.

Я хочу создать приложение на андроид, в котором клиент будет записываться на услугу. Мне подсказали `firebase`, но при работе с ней возникла проблема заполнения её, так как много будет полей (дата ,имя,номер,почта,время) и мне нужно чтобы списки между собой связывались. На примере по дате вывести весь список записанных клиентов или по запросу на дату чтобы выводилось свободное время. Подскажите пожалуйста с чем лучше работать или оставить выбор на `firebase`?

Answer (score 2):

В данной ситуации выбор зависит от ответа на вопрос: *Готовы ли Вы строить всю инфраструктуру самостоятельно и нужно ли вообще оно Вам?*

`Firebase DB` – это облачная `NoSQL` БД с реал-тайм синхронизацией и кучей плюшек, которые Вы получаете прямо **из коробки**.

Если же Вам не хватает возможностей `Firebase DB` и Вы имеете необходимые квалификацию, время и деньги – Вы можете выбрать любую подходящую СУБД, развернуть ее на сервере (а сервер еще нужно где-то взять) и организовать взаимодействие между Вашим приложением и СУБД.